# Multi-container deployment to ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to deploy a multi-container app to ElasticBeanstalk as follows:

1. Upload code to GitHub
2. CodePipeline detects this code and uses CodeBuild to push 3x images to ECR
3. CodeDeploy then deploys a multi-container app on ElasticBeanstalk

(1) and (2) work. I can see the three images on ECR. (3) is failing with the following error:

[image]

I'm supply env variables like AWS_ACCOUNT_ID from the CodeBuild console.

My buildspec.yml file is below.

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      docker: 18
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...
      - aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - echo Building the Docker image...
      - docker-compose --file=docker-compose-prod.yml build
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
      - echo Pushing the Docker image....
      - aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
      - docker-compose --file=docker-compose-prod.yml push
artifacts:
  files:
    - "Dockerrun.aws.json"
```

Dockerrun.aws.json below:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "client",
      "image": "${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.${AWS_REGION}.amazonaws.com/${APPLICATION_NAME}-client:latest",
      "hostname": "client",
      "essential": false,
      "memory": 256
    },
    {
      "name": "api",
      "image": "${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.${AWS_REGION}.amazonaws.com/${APPLICATION_NAME}-api:latest",
      "hostname": "api",
      "essential": false,
      "memory": 128
    },
    {
      "name": "nginx",
      "image": "${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.${AWS_REGION}.amazonaws.com/${APPLICATION_NAME}-nginx:latest",
      "hostname": "nginx",
      "essential": true,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 80,
          "containerPort": 80
        }
      ],
      "links": ["client", "api"],
      "memory": 64
    }
  ]
}
```